# My iPad won't respond to anything.

Tags: ipad

So I have had my iPad for about a year but I haven't used it in a few months. I've been easy on it. It has never fell or anything and now it won't work. When I hold down both buttons (or the power one) absolutely nothing happens. Also when I plug it into my computer iTunes doesn't even recognize it. What can be wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried bacon?

Answer (score 3):

Plug the iPad into the original Apple charger (the one that came with the iPad) for a few hours.  Your computer's USB port may not provide enough power if the iPad's battery is completely discharged.  The iPad charger is rated to provide twice as much charging current as a typical computer USB port.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like time for recovery mode and a possible iTunes update.

So first put your device into [Recovery Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1808) and make sure you are using the latest version of iTunes.

If you cannot put the device in recovery mode, head to an Apple store. If you can then plug into the newly update iTunes and follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 0):

**Long-Term Storage**

If you don’t plan on using your iPod touch for more than three weeks, Apple recommends that you store it with the battery charged between 50%-75% and the device completely turned off, not just put to sleep.

If you store it when the battery is fully discharged, it could fall into a deep discharge state, which renders it incapable of holding any charge. Conversely, if you store it fully charged for an extended period of time, the battery may experience some loss of battery capacity, meaning it will have a shorter life.

I'm not sure if this will apply to your situation or not, seeing as it was intended for iPod's and not iPad's, but I would think that the concept would be the same.

[This](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipods.html) is the apple page where I got the information from.

Comment: This may explain a part of "what can be wrong" but doesn't answer "what can fix it".  Perhaps add a little more to your answer to make it more complete?

Comment: @AdamDavis yes, but unfortunately, i'm actually not quite sure how to fix this, so i thought i would just put up the "why" part, so that megann50.21 wouldn't make the same mistakes later.